# Add random number to all embedded array documents

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

This code adds one random number to all embedded documents, but for each embedded document a random number is needed.

```
app.patch("/updatemany", async (req, res, next) => {
  let a = await listingsAndReview.updateOne(
    { reviews: { $ne: [] } },
    {
      $set: {
        "reviews.$[].rating": Math.round(Math.random() * 4 * 10) / 10 + 1,
      },
    },
    {
      upsert: true,
    }
  );
  res.send(a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is using update with pipeline, along with [`$rand`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rand/):

```
db.collection.updateOne({ reviews: { $ne: [] } },
[
  {
    $set: {
      reviews: {
        $map: {
          input: "$reviews",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {rating: {$rand: {}}}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DUsb6bAptsi)

The range of `$rand` is 0 to 1. You can control the range by using `$multiply`, `$add`...

Comment: $rand is not supported in older mongodb version, is there any other alternative to it , which can support version 3.2

Comment: You can run bulk update